# How can i replace \ with \\ in python?

Tags: python, replace

all I am trying to do is

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
path = path.replace('\', '\\')
```

basically when i find the \ I want it replaced by double \ so i can access the files I want in python

How can this be done?

Comment: This is definitely an [XY issue](http://xyproblem.info/). How are you actually trying to use the path, and how is that failing? The paths given to you by `os.path` should already be perfectly usable for accessing files.

Comment: Basically I am using pyautogui to locate some photos. If I use the 'photoname.png' it does not work and I figured out that I need to have the absolute path for it to work.
Because I want it to work for every user, I am trying to get the path and then add the '\\photoname.png' in the end. If I get the path, though it will output it using the \ character but python wants double \ when using absolute paths. So this is why I want to have the \ replaced

Comment: @HeyYoubooo You shouldn't need to replace the back slash. The path is "dir\dir2\file.png" not "dir\\dir2\file.png" (although that should work too. What tou are probably seeing is that *in code* these paths are written with "\\" - but that's only because *in code* the single \ is used for escape characters. It will eventually get translated into a single \ anyway and that's what the program is using.

Comment: Single vs double \ is likely just a representation issue. Regardless, instead of trying to attach it via string manipulation, just use `os.path.join(dirname, "photoname.png")`.

Comment: If I use only \ I get this error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape . If I use the double \ it works fine

Comment: A single backslash is an escape character which is why you need to use the doubled version, or use raw string literals (`r"like\this"`). But as I already said, you shouldn't be connecting things manually with backslashes in the first place. `os.path.join` exists for exactly this purpose, use it!

Comment: I got it to work using the os.path.join thing, thank you very much tzaman!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
path=os.path.dirname(os.path.reapath(__file__))
path = str(path).replace("\\","\\\\")
```

Comment: The OP does not really want to replace one backslash with two.